# Infinitely Many Bernoulli Sums

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $Y = X_1 + X_2 ...$ where $X_n$ is Bernoulli with $p_n$ and that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}p_n < \infty$.

What is the expectation of $Y$?

Since the expectation of $X_n = p_n$ and the expectation of a sum is the sum of the expectations, the best I can do is say that it is less than infinity. I'm not sure how I can do better than that - I know all $p_n$'s can't be $1$ otherwise the sum would not converge but they can all be $0$, in which case $E[Y] = 0$. They can be anywhere in between too, which would yield different answers.

Comment: You cannot do that any better unless you know the $p_n$'s explicitly. For example $p_n$ could be $\frac1{n^2}$ the you would know the exact sum.

Comment: The expectation of a sum of nonnegative random variables is the sum of the expectations, regardless of whether it is a finite sum or countably infinite sum. So $E[Y] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i$.  This is true regardless of whether $\sum_i p_i < \infty$ or $\sum_i p_i = \infty$.

Comment: If $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i < \infty$, you can conclude (by the Borel-Cantelli lemma) that, with prob 1, all but a finite number of $X_i$ values are $0$.  In particular, $Y$ is finite with prob 1.

Comment: It is not clear why your question discusses cases $p_i=0$ or $p_i=1$, the $p_i$ values can be any number in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Michael Couldn't we draw that conclusion directly without Borel-Cantelli from the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p_n$ is the expectation of $Y$? I'm splitting hairs though.

Comment: @dsaxton , yes, that is true.  Since $E[Y]$ is finite it must be that $Y$ is finite with prob 1.

Comment: @dsaxton , I cannot decide right now which is more fundamental (or, which comes first in the derivation chain), the Borel-Cantelli idea or the idea of passing an expectation thru an infinite sum...somehow the latter seems more complex to me.

Comment: @Ian On second thought I would say Borel-Cantelli is probably more "axiomatic" since it essentially follows from subadditivity of probability.

Comment: @Michael A simple proof of this part of Borel-Cantelli lemma is to use expectations, unsurprisingly--so much so that the question of which is "most fundamental" seems rather moot.